# Help understanding a lemma on modules over a PID.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, proof-explanation, principal-ideal-domains

> **Lemma 1.84**
>
> Let $R$ be a PID. Suppose that $M\simeq R/(a)$ where $a$ is a nonzero element of $R$. Moreover, suppose $p$ is an irreducible element of $R$. Then
>
> (a) If $p\nmid a \implies M_p=\{0\}$ and $pM=M\simeq R/(a)$.
>
> (b) If $p\mid a \implies M_p\simeq R/(p)$ and $pM\simeq R/(a/p)$

The proof for part (a) is:

> *Proof.*  Suppose $p\nmid a$. Then since $p$ is irreducible, $p$ and $a$ are relatively prime. Also $aM=\{0\}$. Hence, $paM=\{0\}$. Thus
>   $$ aM=M_p \text{ and } pM=M_a $$
>   and
>   $$ M=M_a\oplus M_p$$
>   as proven before if $a$ and $p$ are relatively prime.
>
> So $$M_p=aM=\{0\}$$
>   Also $M=M_a\oplus M_p=M_a\oplus\{0\}=M_a$ and so
>   $$pM=M_a=M\simeq R/(a).$$

The definition for $aM$ and $M_a$ is:
$$aM=\{ax:x\in M\} \text{ and } M_a=\{x\in M:ax=0\}$$

My only question for the above proof is how come $aM=\{0\}$? I was playing around with the assumptions, and I've failed to conclude why we can say that.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: My guess is $M$ is isomorphic to $R/(a)$. Hence the image of $aM\cong aR/(a) = 0$.

Comment: $M$ is given as isomorphic to $R/(a)$. Once you take any element $r+(a)$ of $M$, if you multiply by $a$ you get $ar+(a)=0+(a)$.